# SecureRandom in C#

Tags: c#, java

Here is the java code:

```java
SecureRandom random = SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG");
random.setSeed(someBytes);//someBytes is the seed
```

Is there any equal method in C#? What I have get is not correct:

```
RandomNumberGenerator rng = RNGCryptoServiceProvider.Create();
rng.GetBytes(someBytes);// out someBytes
```

I do need the seed, because the java code did, I have to translate the java code into C#.  When I pass the same seed, the sequence I get from C# must equal with the java.

Comment: What is incorrect about your code?

Comment: in the java code, "someBytes" is the seed, in C# "someBytes" is the container.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4892588/rngcryptoserviceprovider-random-number-review

Comment: Please comment on *why* do you need to seed it? I.e for unit tests you can create your own version of RandomGenerator that does whatever you want...

Comment: I need the seed, because the java code did, I have to translate the java code into C#.

Comment: That's not a very helpful answer to "Why".  Are you expecting the C# RNG to provide the same sequence of values as the Java RNG, or are you just trying to get the same sequence of values every time you pass the same seed?

Comment: " Are you expecting the C# RNG to provide the same sequence of values as the Java RNG?"YES

Comment: That's not going to happen. The values are implementation-specific, so it depends not only on the seed, but also on the algorithm. You *are not* going to get the same values.

Comment: If you need the exact same values, then I suggest saving them from the Java implementation and saving them to disk. Your current efforts are futile.

Comment: If you really-really need to do it, check the source code for SecureRandom & SHA1PRNG implementation and try to port them.

Comment: I have downvoted because your question fails to understand the meaning of a cryptographic random generator. You will never be able to determine the values coming out. (and therefore, the goal of duplicating them will never be achievable)

Comment: @DouglasHeld The question is good, even if the idea to use it as a KDF is terrible. And Java does or at least did act as a deterministic random number generator if you set the seed before you use it, although the SUN provided algorithm is undescribed. So "you will never be able to determine the values coming out" is - certainly in practice - false. Especially for a specific JVM version.

Answer (score 9):

The abstract class `System.Security.Cryptography.RandomNumberGenerator` and its concrete implementations do not expose a method for setting a seed to the developer (though internally, I suspect they do in fact use one.)

The design rationale there was, I suspect, that repeatability does not make for a 'cryptographically strong' stream of random values.

If you look at the concrete implementation, `RNGCryptoServiceProvider`, while it does expose a constructor accepting a `byte[]` to presumably initialize the PRNG, its documentation says

> This value is ignored.

And the remarks go on to say

> This method does not directly initialize the RNGCryptoServiceProvider class.
>   Calling this method is equivalent to calling the RNGCryptoServiceProvider
>   constructor and passing **null**.

For information on the sort of stuff that goes into the seed that's used, see the MSDN documentation for [`CryptGenRandom`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/aa379942)

Comment: Is the any likely method with seed?

Answer (score 7):

According to the MSDN docs for [`RNGCryptoServiceProvider`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rngcryptoserviceprovider.aspx) there doesn't appear to be a way to manually seed it with values yourself. There are constructors that take a [`byte[]`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s3bz1e1a.aspx) and [`string`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y3dh7bhb.aspx), but *both of those arguments are ignored*.

This doesn't matter, because any random number generator worth its weight in salt will properly seed itself upon creation. Any value you provide is unlikely to be any better than the internal seeding mechanism (which is probably a high-resolution time-derived value).

Comment: Why do you think you have to seed it?

Comment: The only reason for specifying a specific seed is to get a repeatable result (useful for, say, testing). And even if you **could** seed `RNGCryptoServiceProvider`, the only way you'll get the exact same stream values is if both implementations use the exact same algorithm. And Microsoft's documentation doesn't specify the algorithm in use that I can find. The documentation for `CryptGenRandom()` suggests that the algorithm varies with the operating system.

Comment: Theoretically, an implementation could be using Intel's [DRNG](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-digital-random-number-generator-drng-software-implementation-guide) at which point the seed wouldn't guarantee the same output of numbers.

Regardless, the question is totally pointless. You *cannot* seed this class. If you want to test with a predefined string of numbers, then make an interface, and substitute it with a mock RNG. Fin.

Comment: The problem is that the SHA1PRNG class is often **incorrectly** used as a deterministic (password based) key derivation function. In that case just setting a seed is not enough, you must emulate the SHA1PRNG algorithm, which - rather unhelpfully - is unspecified.