# Generate random alphanumeric string with condition in C#

Tags: c#, .net, regex

According to following code , I need to generate a string in different cases based on the method input. My issue is where I wanna generate **9A9A** (at least 1 number and 1 letter) or **9A9A9A** (at least 2 numbers and 2 letters). In most cases, this conditions is not met.

```
private AuthMessage GetAuthCode(string CodeType) //(out string Message)
    {
        Guid Guid = Guid.NewGuid();
        Random Random = new Random();
        string AuthCode = string.Empty;
        string RefCode = string.Empty;

        RefCode = Guid.ToString("N");

        switch (CodeType)
        {
            case "0": //9999
                {
                    AuthCode = Random.Next(1000, 9999).ToString();
                    break;
                }
            case "1": //99999
                {
                    AuthCode = Random.Next(10000, 99999).ToString();
                    break;
                }
            case "2": //999999
                {
                    AuthCode = Random.Next(100000, 999999).ToString();
                    break;
                }
            case "3": //999-999
                {
                    AuthCode = Regex.Replace(Random.Next(100000, 999999).ToString(), @"^(.{3})(.{3})$", "$1-$2");
                    break;
                }
            case "4": //9A9A
                {
                    AuthCode = Guid.ToString("N").Substring(14, 4).ToUpper();
                    break;
                }
            case "5": //9A9A9
                {
                    AuthCode = Guid.ToString("N").Substring(15, 5).ToUpper();
                    break;
                }
            case "6": //9A9A9A
                {
                    AuthCode = Guid.ToString("N").Substring(6, 6).ToUpper();
                    break;
                }
            case "7": //9A9-A9A
                {
                    AuthCode = Regex.Replace(Guid.ToString("N").Substring(6, 6), @"(.{3})(.{3})", @"$1-$2").ToUpper();
                    break;
                }
            case "8": //9A9-A9A
                {
                    AuthCode = Regex.Replace(Regex.Replace(Convert.ToBase64String(Guid.ToByteArray()), "[/+=]", "").Substring(0, 6), @"(.{3})(.{3})", @"$1-$2").ToUpper();
                    break;
                }
            default:
                {
                    AuthCode = Random.Next(1000, 9999).ToString();
                    break;
                }
        }

        AuthMessage Response = new AuthMessage();
        Response.AuthCode = AuthCode;
        Response.RefCode = RefCode;

     return Response;
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'condition is not met'? Are cases 5 and 6 not working?

Comment: from case 4 using GUID substring doesn't guarantee you that you will get string containing combination of character and number. Like you want 9A9A. so taking substring of GUID doesn't give you 2 number and 2 character. You have to implement your own logic here.

Comment: This is a **terrible** use of guids and you should not do this.  Guids have one purpose and one purpose only: to produce a *globally unique ID*.  A guid is not guaranteed to be *random*. Any *portion* of a guid is not guaranteed to be unique.  Solve the problem you have by *solving the problem you have*, not by using the guid generator as an engine to solve a problem completely unrelated to unique identifier generation.

Comment: In particular, even for *random* type-4 guids one of your cases includes some of the *non random* data that is in a type-4 guid. And of course a GUID never contains letters other than A-F.

Comment: Moreover, you have a larger problem here. **You are using non-crypto-strength randomness**, which means that an attacker who has compromised **one** of your authorization codes can easily generate **all the rest of them**, or at least have a solid guess as to what all the rest of them are. My advice is that you should **stop writing this code and hire a security expert** who actually knows how to implement authorization schemes safely.

Comment: Actually, it is even worse than that, now that I look at the code more carefully. **An attacker can determine what a likely authorization code is simply by knowing what time the code was generated**, since you are not following best practices for managing instances of `Random`.

Comment: @EricLippert our company uses a service to scan and find any security issues with our code and provides a report which we then resolve any issues. But it is still **up to us to write the code**. When you say "stop writing this code and hire a security expert", is that **the answer**? The user wants to write secure code and is posting such a question on SO for guidance. If there is a patent reason(s) to not write code, why isn't that an answer provided below?

Comment: @OmegaMan: There is an **enormous** difference between "wanting to write secure code" -- that is, line of business code which does not accidentally introduce a vulnerability -- and writing Security Code -- that is, encryption, authorization systems, and the like. The latter is one of the hardest tasks in computer programming and should be left to experts who have spent years studying it. You can't obtain correct Security Code by getting an amateur to throw something together and then have strangers on the internet critique it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I thought I'd have a go - it gives me a good chance of being ridiculed. This isn't the most efficient way of generating the codes, but it should be fairly random.

```
private string GetAuthCode(string CodeType)
{
    var patterns = new Dictionary<char, Func<Char>>()
    {
        { '9', () => RandomBytes().Where(x => x >= '0' && x <= '9').First() },
        { 'A', () => RandomBytes().Where(x => x >= 'A' && x <= 'Z').First() },
        { '-', () => '-' },
    };

    return
        String.IsNullOrEmpty(CodeType)
            ? ""
            : patterns[CodeType[0]]().ToString() + GetAuthCode(CodeType.Substring(1));
}

private IEnumerable<char> RandomBytes()
{
    using (var rng = System.Security.Cryptography.RNGCryptoServiceProvider.Create())
    {
        var bytes = new byte[256];
        while (true)
        {
            rng.GetBytes(bytes);
            foreach (var @byte in bytes)
            {
                yield return (char)@byte;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now, due to the funky monkey state machine that implements iterator methods, this code does dispose of the RNG despite the `while (true)`.

I simplified the `GetAuthCode` method slightly, but I think this demonstrates a suitable way to generate the codes.

Comment: This is super-inefficient: Silly use of recursion, generating RNG that you aren't using, regenerating the service provider repeatedly (which is safe, unlike with `Random`).  It's also ugly that the `CodeType` impacts performance, though `CodeType` isn't a secret, so this isn't a disaster.  All that being said, this is the first code-based answer that I can't find a security flaw in.  Of course, I'm an amateur. [Schneier's Law](https://www.schneier.com/blog/archives/2011/04/schneiers_law.html) applies.

Comment: @Brian - Yes, I agree it is inefficient, but I suspect it's not going to be used in a tight loop. I feel fairly happy with it.

Answer (score 4):

`Guid` representation is composed of hexadecimal digits, i.e. characters `0`-`9` and `a`-`f`. The problem with relying on it to obtain a mixture of letters and numbers is that a character at any given position could be either a letter or a decimal digit, with probability tilted roughly 5:3 in favor of a decimal digit.

If you want to generate a specific mix of digits and letters, you should generate the string one character at a time, without relying on `Guid` representation.

Comment: how about regex methods, can be used?

Comment: @AmirHusseinKhaniki Regex methods are for searching strings, not for generating them. You could generate random strings and then check them with regex, but your code would be cleaner and easier to maintain if you generate what you need in one go, as opposed to trial-and-error.

Comment: I mean to use regex methods for filtering generated guid string base on condition

Comment: @AmirHusseinKhaniki You can filter it, sure, but then are you going to try repeatedly generate a string until you get a match? What if the match does not come up within a reasonable time? After all, this is a random string, it can be a while before you get a match. What's wrong with generating the string yourself?

Answer (score -2):

```
public class TokenCreator
{
 private Random random = new Random();
 private const string[] chars= "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789"
 public static string CreateToken(int length)
 {
    return new string(Enumerable.Repeat(chars, length)
      .Select(s => s[random.Next(s.Length)]).ToArray());
 }
}

AuthCode = TokenCreator.CreateToken(5);
```

This implementation can little help you. But again it doesn't guarantee you get alphanumeric combination. Sometime you may get only alphabets and sometime you may get only numbers. Though chances are so little.

Comment: Don't use `Random` to generate authentication codes.

Answer (score -2):

**OverView** The following code uses `Regex.Replace` along woth `IsMatch` which allows one to create an any length pattern such as `XXXXXX` or `XX-XX` which will replace any `X` with a random character or letter.

For example `XX-XX` could return `A(-1d` or with dashes just `XXXX` to `A(1d`.

**Security**
It uses the `Web.Security.Membership.GeneratePassword` to get a string of 48 random characters, digits and what not. Then a clear password is culled from that random characters based on the pattern needed.

> (at least 1 number and 1 letter)

This is done in the validation regex which assures there is atleast one alphabetic character and one number. That generate method is called until that validation reports a valid match from the rules you mentioned.

**Secure Transport**
Finally a secure string is setup to be returned.

This one works off of getting a

```
// This pattern enforces our rule that a pwd must have one letter and one digit.
string pattern = @" # This regex pattern enforces the rules before returning matching
(?=.*[a - zA - Z])  # Somewhere there is a an alphabectic character
(?=.*\d)            # Somewhere there is a number; if no number found return no match.
(.+)                # Successful match, rules are satisfied. Return match";

Random rn = new Random(); // Used to cherry pick from chars to use.

// Creates 48 alpha and non alpha (at least 10 non digit alphas) random characters.
string charsToUse = System.Web.Security.Membership.GeneratePassword(48, 5);

// When replacement is done, replace an `X` matched with a random char. 
MatchEvaluator RandomChar = delegate (Match m)
{
    return charsToUse[rn.Next(charsToUse.Length)].ToString();
};

Func<string, string> Validate = 
      (string str) => Regex.IsMatch(str, pattern, RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace) 
                      ? str : string.Empty; // return empty on failure.

string pwdClear = string.Empty;

// Generate valid pwd based on rules. Loop until rules are met.
while (string.IsNullOrEmpty(pwdClear))
    pwdClear = Validate(Regex.Replace("XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX", "X", RandomChar));

// Create a secure string for the password for transportation.
SecureString ss = new SecureString();

pwdClear.ToList()
        .ForEach(chr => ss.AppendChar(chr));
```

---

This answer is based off of a non-secure implementation on my blog see [C#: Generate a Random Sequence of Numbers and Letters From a User Defined Pattern and Characters](http://omegacoder.com/?p=531)

Comment: Don't use `Random` to generate authentication codes.

Comment: @Brian Fair enough, but what should one use? Where is your answer to this question?

Comment: I'd use `System.Security.Cryptography.RNGCryptoServiceProvider` to generate passwords.  That said, my preference is `System.Web.Security.Membership.GeneratePassword`.  If you're lazy, you can abuse `Path.GetRandomFileName`.  That's somewhat inappropriate/off-label, but it *is* [documented](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getrandomfilename.aspx) as returning "a cryptographically strong, random string."

Comment: As for why I'm not providing an answer: I don't consider myself a security expert, so I take it for granted that any answer I provide will be wrong.  While I believe my answer would be better, it would still have a high risk of being wrong, albeit more subtly wrong than using `Random`. My general recommendation to any security question is, "use one that was built by experts," but that's rather unhelpful when the OP is asking for special-case code.

Comment: @Brian Used the `GeneratePassword` you mentioned to generate uber password, then cherry pick from that password. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, but you're still using `Random` to pick characters from `charsToUse`.  Even though `charsToUse` is random, this is still unsafe, as this makes the odds of a given password character matching another password character slightly different from true random.

Answer (score -3):

For testing purposes, when I need to generate random strings with specific properties, I use something similar to this. You might have to adapt it to your needs.

```
public sealed class StringGenerator
{
  private static readonly char[] NumericChars = "0123456789".ToCharArray();
  private static readonly char[] LowerAlphaChars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".ToCharArray();
  private static readonly char[] UpperAlphaChars = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ".ToCharArray();

  public StringGenerator(IRandom rnd)
  {
    Rnd = rnd ?? new SecureRandom();
  }

  private IRandom Rnd
  {
    get;
    set;
  }

  public string Generate(int length, int minNumeric = 0, int minAlpha = 0, AlphaCase alphaCase = AlphaCase.Both)
  {
    if (length < 0)
    {
      throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("length");
    }
    if (minNumeric < 0)
    {
      throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("minNumeric");
    }
    if (minAlpha < 0)
    {
      throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("minAlpha");
    }
    if (length < minNumeric + minAlpha)
    {
      throw new ArgumentException();
    }

    if (length == 0)
    {
      return string.Empty;
    }

    var result = new char[length];

    var index = 0;

    foreach(var numeric in GenerateNumeric().Take(minNumeric))
    {
      result[index++] = numeric;
    }

    var alphaCharacters = GetAlphaCharacters(alphaCase);
    foreach (var alpha in Generate(alphaCharacters).Take(minAlpha))
    {
      result[index++] = alpha;
    }


    var restLength = length - index;

    if (restLength > 0)
    {
      var restCharacters = new List<char>(NumericChars.Concat(alphaCharacters));

      foreach (var rest in Generate(restCharacters).Take(restLength))
      {
        result[index++] = rest;
      }
    }

    // shuffle result
    return new string(result.OrderBy(x => Rnd.Next()).ToArray());
  }

  private IList<char> GetAlphaCharacters(AlphaCase alphaCase)
  {
    switch (alphaCase)
    {
      case AlphaCase.Lower:
        return LowerAlphaChars;

      case AlphaCase.Upper:
        return UpperAlphaChars;

      case AlphaCase.Both:
      default:
        return new List<char>(LowerAlphaChars.Concat(UpperAlphaChars));
    }
  }

  public IEnumerable<char> GenerateNumeric()
  {
    return Generate(NumericChars);
  }
  public IEnumerable<char> GenerateLowerAlpha()
  {
    return Generate(LowerAlphaChars);
  }
  public IEnumerable<char> GenerateUpperAlpha()
  {
    return Generate(UpperAlphaChars);
  }

  public IEnumerable<char> Generate(IList<char> characters)
  {
    if (characters == null)
    {
      throw new ArgumentNullException();
    }
    if (!characters.Any())
    {
      yield break;
    }

    while (true)
    {
      yield return characters[Rnd.Next(characters.Count)];
    }
  }
}

public enum AlphaCase
{
  Lower,
  Upper,
  Both
}

public interface IRandom
{
    int Next();
    int Next(int maxValue);
}

public sealed class SecureRandom : IRandom
{
    private readonly RandomNumberGenerator Rng = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider();

    public int Next()
    {
        var data = new byte[sizeof(int)];
        Rng.GetBytes(data);
        return BitConverter.ToInt32(data, 0) & (int.MaxValue - 1);
    }

    public int Next(int maxValue)
    {
        return Next(0, maxValue);
    }

    public int Next(int minValue, int maxValue)
    {
        if (minValue > maxValue)
        {
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
        }
        return (int)Math.Floor(minValue + ((double)maxValue - minValue) * NextDouble());
    }

    public double NextDouble()
    {
        var data = new byte[sizeof(uint)];
        Rng.GetBytes(data);
        var randomUint = BitConverter.ToUInt32(data, 0);
        return randomUint / (uint.MaxValue + 1d);
    }
}
```

---

Edit: This is an answer to the question of how to generate random alphanumeric strings with conditions. As stated for testing purposes. Not to be used as is in a context where security is relevant.

---

Edit 2: Shamelessly borrowing from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16907577/1336590), the solution now uses a wrapper around [RNGCryptoServiceProvider](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.security.cryptography.rngcryptoserviceprovider.aspx). Still not sure if this should be used in security relevant context, but at least now it should be "better" than simply using `Random`